# Windows Boot on 2nd Hard Disc Drive

Tags: dual-boot

I have ventured into the Ubunta world.  I decided to completely ditch Windows so I didn't do a Windows and Ubuntu install but just installed Ubuntu 12.04.  Because I can't sync my iphone I have installed a second HDD with XP on it?  How do I get the option to boot XP.  I seem to only be able to find answers with Windows on HDD1 and Ubuntu on HDD2

Comment: "How do I get the option to boot XP. I seem to only be able to find answers with Windows on HDD1 and Ubuntu on HDD2" -- that sounds EXACTLY like what you want to do. Please reformulate your question so it makes sense. Please outline what you are seeing now and what you want to see when you are done.

Comment: Yes it is what I want to do but how do I get Ubuntu to give me the option to boot Windows from the second hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `GRUB` as a bootloader you should be able to simply run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu , this till trigger `GRUB` to look for new disks and operating systems. See also [update-grub man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-grub.8.html).

If you are not running GRUB but the Windows bootloader, you can modify that screen with [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

Comment: Thank you. I did updated the grub and it gave me the option to boot XP. I of course got the Blue Screen of Death but that is not a problem for here. Just makes me so much happier I have made the switch.  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Glad to have helped. You might want to look into running Windows XP within Virtualbox instead, that way you could run "only" Ubuntu and boot up XP virtually when you need to do iTunes (or other Windows-specific) stuff.

Comment: Yeah I think your right.  Might do that right now